# Octave generate combination subsets

Tags: matlab, combinations, octave

Given a number `N`, I would like to create a matrix of `x` columns with every combination of a subset of `N`. For example, if `N` is `16` and `x` is `3` then I should get a matrix of 560 rows and each row will have 3 columns and contain a unique combination from the numbers 1 to 16.
Can I use a function `zzz(N,x)` ?
I will be generating a lot of them with different `N` and `x` values so a for loop will slow things down.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? Have your read any manual, probably you can write this function if it is not already created in octave (I don't know octave).

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [`nchoosek`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/nchoosek.html) function:

```
N = 16;
x = 3;
nchoosek(1:N, x)
```

returns 560 rows like this:

```
    .    .    .
    .    .    .
    .    .    .
    1    2   13
    1    2   14
    1    2   15
    1    2   16
    1    3    4
    1    3    5
    1    3    6
    1    3    7
    .    .    .
    .    .    .
    .    .    .
```